# Co-pilot doesnt work proberly on Visual Studio 2022 'ReturnKeyCommandArgs'?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, github-copilot

Im having an issue with my co-pilot installation on Visual Studio 2022, im running the stable community version, and im running it with extensions, of course. However, i **HAVE** tried disabling **AND** uninstalling all my extensions, and it will still not work the way it should.
Co-pilot works fine on Visual Studio Code, its only Visual Studio 2022 that im having issues with.

The exact exception im getting is as follows:

```cs
[Error] An error occurred for 'ReturnKeyCommandArgs': StreamJsonRpc.RemoteInvocationException: Request getCompletions failed with message: The operation was aborted.
   at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.<InvokeCoreAsync>d__143`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at GitHub.Copilot.CopilotCommandHandler.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<<ExecuteCommandCore>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.VsTaskLibraryHelper.<>c__DisplayClass35_0.<<FileAndForget>b__0>d.MoveNext()

( A lot of the same exception above here... )
```

For my attempts to fix this, I have tried:

- **Uninstalling/Disabling all my extensions**
- **Reinstalling Visual Studio 2022**
- **Reinstalling Copilot**
- **Tried experimental releases of copilot**
- **Cleared Visual Studio Cache**
- **Changed default keybinds**
- **Unauthorized and then authorized copilot again**
- **Tried other coding languages (C#, C/C++, even Python, HTML and PHP (Yes i know its meant to be done in VS Code, its for testing...))**

Please if you have had this issue before, and have recently fixed it, please share your solution. I've seen multiple people having the same issue as me, however with no current solution.

I would preferebly stay with **Visual Studio 2022** specifically, and not older versions or any other third party, as its my main IDE, and i use it for all my needs.

EDIT: I did absoloutely nothing, and after a week, i tried to activate copilot globally again, and it magically works... what...